# Appium on Windows for Android : Command failed: can't find 'C:\Program' to install

Tags: android, windows, appium

Attempting to just start up Appium with an emulator using an example program.

Output:

```
debug: executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 install C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk
warn:  killed=false, code=1, signal=null
info: Stopping logcat capture
info: Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
info: Cleaning up android objects
info: Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: can't find 'C:\Program' to install

info: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: can't find 'C:\\Program' to install\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: can't find 'C:\\Program' to install\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
POST /wd/hub/session 500 11733ms - 316b
```

Tried with an emulator with the apk already installed and a fresh emulator, get the same result.

code:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.SetCapability("device", "Android");
    caps.SetCapability("browserName", "");
    caps.SetCapability("app-activity", "MainActivity");
    caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "4.2");
    caps.SetCapability("app-package", "com.example.android.interactivechart");
    caps.SetCapability("app", @"C:\scm\InteractiveChart\out\production\InteractiveChart\InteractiveChart.apk");

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps, new TimeSpan(0,5,0)); //error here
```

Anyone know why it's doing this? I've had a look around and I can't find anything. It's probably something simple but the 'C:\Program' is throwing me since I don't pass in anything containing this.

Edit: added windows tag as the default install locations were the source of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Appium but it seems like it has a problem with the directory name,The  directory should not have a space while using some command line tools,move the Android sdk and Appium folders to a directory with no spaces (like to C:) and try the command with that directory.

Comment: I agree this is a possibility but since this is on windows I'll have to re-install the whole android studio to a custom location to test it, I'll be a while.

Comment: no need,just need to copy the sdk folder to any other location and run the command

Comment: All the devices are in the studio as well, the whole thing would need to be moved. Already tested with just copying the sdk(and changing the path variable) and appium directories out to C:

Comment: The devices(u mean AVDs?) are in %USERPROFILE%/.android folder there's  no problem in moving the sdk folder or the android studio folder itself to another folder since android studio does not have any registry entries( at least nothing that can be re-configured )

Comment: ahh no you were right I take it back, no idea why it failed the first time but its running now with appium and the sdk moved out. Irritating since they are in standard windows install folders.